# How to integrate meteor in SauceLabs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, meteor-blaze, saucelabs

I am working on a meteor-balze app.

I have started to write mocha test cases for this app. And I want to use mocha with SauceLabs.

But I am not getting any helpful link for it. I go through below links:

https://saucelabs.com/products/javascript-unit-testing/mocha-js

https://github.com/pbakaus/mocha-sauce

I also add mocha-sauce package and also take clone from its repository and tried to run its dummy app but getting below errors:-

```
{ 
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
        at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
        at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444
}
```

There is no video available on YouTube for integrating mocha with saucelabs.

Please advise how I can integrate mochaJS with SauceLabs.

Thanks & Regards,

Saransh

Comment: what is wrong exactly with those URLs?